# How to get list Elements using linq, C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

*my code bellow:*

[image]

```
My xml file:
```

[image]

I have a question, How to get list cmd base on profile id?

Comment: Please copy-paste XML code and your parsing code. Then select it all and press `Code Sample` button in editor. Don't paste screenshots of code

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuang - It's very important to **show us what you've tried**, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: sorry, I tried post code but I can't post. I was press Code Sample button in editor and not resolv. and I insert image very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Getting `Cmd` elements of given `Profile`:

```
int id = 0;
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

var result = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Profile")
             where (int)p.Element("Id") == id
             from cmd in p.Element("Command").Elements()
             select cmd;
```

Or lambda syntax:

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Profile")
                 .Where(p => (int)p.Element("Id") == id)
                 .SelectMany(p => p.Element("Command").Elements());
```

Comment: cmd include Path and Value, I wish get cmd.Path and cmd.Value and convert cmd into List<Command>. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuang I can, but please, format your question appropriately - replace each image with code text

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuang if you have some problems with formatting code, feel free to ask me

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved my problem. I was using your code.

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuang I already have complete solution :) I just want to teach you asking questions on StackOverflow. Otherwise you will be downovted as now and usually people don't answer badly formatted questions

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved my problem. I am using your code.

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuang as you wish. Another advice - mark answer as accepted if helped you to solve problem (green arrow to the left side). I can see you didn't accept any answers. None of them helped to solve your problems?